# How does InterfaceController access objects created in ViewController?

Tags: swift

If I created an array of objects in my ViewController, how do I then access this array in my InterfaceController file? Trying to access myArray says I'm referring to a variable that is unresolved.

```
import UIKit

var myArray = [Kana]()

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    // insert code to input objects into myArray

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `InterfaceController` ?

Comment: InterfaceController.swift , the default file that accesses your UI elements.

Comment: I think your project is relating to MVC. InterfaceController is son of UIKit. Create a class to store data array with import UIkit on top, and you can call it everywhere if your controller is using UIKit

Comment: do you mind elaborating a bit more? i already have a class called Kana, and i want to create an array of Kana objects to be used across various controllers.